# How to avoid repeated requests in Cypress tests

Tags: cypress

Since aliases are cleared after each test (`it`) when using Cypress, it seems subsequent tests needs to execute the same request again and again, while I would prefer to get it only once. This can be verified by replacing `beforeEach` with `before`, resulting in the second and third test to fail. Of course all assertions could be placed in a single `it`, I want each assertion to be reported separately however. Why does Cypress need to reload the resource for each test and how can this be avoided?

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

describe('When requesting the resource', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.request('http://startpage.com/').as('response');
    });

    it('The status code should be 200', () => {
        cy.get('@response').its('status').should('be.ok');
    });

    it('The content type should be text/html', () => {
        cy.get('@response').its('headers.content-type').should('include', 'text/html');
    });

    it('The content should be encoded using UTF-8', () => {
        cy.get('@response').its('headers.content-type').should('include', 'charset=utf-8');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliases in Cypress are removed between tests, that's why your `response` alias is not preserved. A discussion around this topic could be found e.g. [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/5351).

What works is this code:

```javascript
const { expect } = require("chai")

describe('When requesting the resource', () => {

    let response;

    before(() => {
        cy.request('http://startpage.com/').then(res => response = res);
    });

    it('The status code should be 200', () => {        
        expect(response.status).to.equal(200);
    });

    it('The content type should be text/html', () => {
        expect(response.headers['content-type']).to.include('text/html');
    });

    it('The content should be encoded using UTF-8', () => {
        expect(response.headers['content-type']).to.include('charset=utf-8');
    });
});
```

you can see that `cy.request()` was run only once:

[image]

On the other hand, I don't consider this a nice solution, because it works only because you know that `before()` runs before all the tests, that's why you can rely on `response` having a value. But if you ever want to do something like this:

```javascript
before(() => {
    cy.request('http://startpage.com/').then(res => response = res);
    console.log(response); // or any other usage of response variable
});
```

it will *not* work because you're mixing asynchronous and synchronous code, so by the time `console.log(response)` executes, `response` is still `undefined`.

---

So if there's a better solution, please post it and I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your clearly formulated answer and provided solution.

Storing the response in a variable seems a nice solution to me, but for some reason the Cypress documentation doesn't recommend this: "We could make our code do some ugly backflips using let to get access to it", followed by demo code with an identical structure as in your answer, accompanied with a warning not to use code like this. And then followed by the recommendation to use aliases instead. But why? And why clear aliases?

Comment: Ah, issue concerning aliases being cleared has been reopened again: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/665#

Comment: Yes, this code is not ideal, that's what I tried to formulate in my answer as well. I know Cypress doesn't recommend that, I've read that doc page a few times. I think the reason is mostly what I said, plus it doesn't look nice :D If your test suite is simple like this example, and you are aware of it not being the right solution but can't find a better one, I'd go for it.